# WP8 - How to read a text file LINE BY LINE?

Tags: windows-phone-8, readline

Basically I was just playing around with the provided sample of the Protect data and how you can encrypt your text file and what not. I managed to do a bit of modification and this is what i have soo far:
Below is my XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">


    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Secure DATA" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Encrypt" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top">


        <TextBlock Margin="10,333,22,405" >
            <Run Text="Enter your "/>
            <Run Text="ACCOUNT PASSWORD:"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="TBPin" Height="75" Width="444" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,355,0,338" InputScope="Number" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnStore" Content="Save" Click="BtnStore_Click" Margin="0,585,222,103" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.481" />
        <Button x:Name="BtnRetrieve" Content="Load" Click="BtnRetrieve_Click" Margin="221,585,12,103" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" />
        <TextBlock Margin="10,157,22,580" >
            <Run Text="Enter your "/>
            <Run Text="ACCOUNT NAME"/>
            <Run Text=":"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="AccName" Width="444" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,177,0,516" Height="75" InputScope="Chat" Text="LoL" />
        <TextBlock Margin="10,244,22,494" >
            <Run Text="Enter your "/>
            <Run Text="ACCOUNT USERNAME:"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="AccUser" Height="75" Width="444" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,266,0,427" />
        <TextBlock Margin="10,423,22,315" Text="Notes about this account:" />
        <TextBox x:Name="AccNotes" Width="444" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,445,0,170" InputScope="Chat" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Below is the Code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Shell
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Private FilePath As String = "Pinfile"

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait Or SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape
End Sub
Private Sub WritePinToFile(pinData As Byte())
    ' Create a file in the application's isolated storage.
    Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim writestream As New IsolatedStorageFileStream(AccName.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, file)
    ' Write pinData to the file.
    Dim writer As Stream = New StreamWriter(writestream).BaseStream
    writer.Write(pinData, 0, pinData.Length)
    writer.Close()
    writestream.Close()
End Sub
Private Function ReadPinFromFile() As Byte()
    ' Access the file in the application's isolated storage.
    Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim readstream As New IsolatedStorageFileStream(AccName.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, file)
    ' Read the PIN from the file.
    Dim reader As Stream = New StreamReader(readstream).BaseStream
    Dim pinArray As Byte() = New Byte(reader.Length - 1) {}
    reader.Read(pinArray, 0, pinArray.Length)
    reader.Close()
    readstream.Close()
    Return pinArray
End Function
Private Sub BtnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Convert the PIN to a byte[].
    Dim PinByte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AccName.Text & vbNewLine & AccUser.Text & vbNewLine & TBPin.Text & vbNewLine & AccNotes.Text)
    ' Encrypt the PIN by using the Protect() method.
    Dim ProtectedPinByte As Byte() = ProtectedData.Protect(PinByte, Nothing)
    ' Store the encrypted PIN in isolated storage.
    Me.WritePinToFile(ProtectedPinByte)
    TBPin.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub BtnRetrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Retrieve the PIN from isolated storage.
    Dim ProtectedPinByte As Byte() = Me.ReadPinFromFile()
    ' Decrypt the PIN by using the Unprotect method.
    Dim PinByte As Byte() = ProtectedData.Unprotect(ProtectedPinByte, Nothing)
    ' Convert the PIN from byte to string and display it in the text box.
    AccName.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length)
    AccUser.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length)
    TBPin.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length)
    AccNotes.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length)

End Sub
End Class
```

Soo far I click store and it stores and when I want to load i just type the name i saved the information with and it loads. **The problem I'm having is that once i click Load it loads everything in that one textfile into every other textbox. This picture will illustrate my point better: http://puu.sh/5T4mc.png**

As you can see it loads everything in one textbox for each and every textbox there is. **What I want to do is e.g. For the Username textbox I want the first line only to show, Password textbox I want the 3rd line of that textfile only to show.** How can i achieve this?

*If possible VB code would be good but C# would also be fine. I could just convert it.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the string, just use `Split` to retrieve each line, then assign them to the textbox you want. In C# it would be:

```
var PinByte = ProtectedData.Unprotect(ProtectedPinByte, null);
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length);
var lines = content.Split('\n');

AccName.Text = lines[0]; // Take the first line
TBPin.Text = lines[2]; // Take the third line
// and so on
```

My VB is rusted, but I believe it would be something like:

```
Dim ProtectedPinByte As Byte() = Me.ReadPinFromFile()
Dim PinByte As Byte() = ProtectedData.Unprotect(ProtectedPinByte, Nothing)
Dim content As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length)
Dim lines As String() = content.Split(vbLf)

AccName.Text = lines(0)
TBPin.Text = lines(2)
```

Comment: Hey! thanks soo much for that I'm gonna give it a try soon and I'll let you know :)